# How to change size and color of appended text in java

Tags: java, fonts

I am working with a block of code that contains multiple lines of appended text. Is there a simple method to change the font color and size? I am specifically looking to change the font size of the appended text like sb.append(record.getSegText())?

Below is the code.

```
    @Override
public String inspect(ReferencedCoordinate coord) throws VizException {
    if (resourceData.hideSampling) {
        return "";
    }
    // check if we are in the last frame
    boolean lastFrame = false;
    FramesInfo framesInfo = this.descriptor.getFramesInfo();

    if (time != null) {
        try {
            Point point = gf.createPoint(coord.asLatLon());

            for (String key : entryMap.keySet()) {

                WarningEntry entry = entryMap.get(key);
                AbstractWarningRecord record = entry.record;
                if (matchesFrame(entry, time, framePeriod, lastFrame)
                        && record.getGeometry() != null) {

                    Geometry recordGeom = record.getGeometry();
                    for (int i = 0; i < recordGeom.getNumGeometries(); i++) {
                        PreparedGeometry prepGeom = pgf.create(recordGeom
                                .getGeometryN(i));

                        if (prepGeom.contains(point)) {
                            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                            String[] textToPrint = getText(record, 0);
                            for (String text : textToPrint) {
                                if (sb.length() > 0) {
                                    sb.append(" ");
                                }
                                sb.append("\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                                sb.append(text);
                                sb.append(record.getSegText());
                            }
                            return sb.toString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    return "NO DATA";
}
```

Comment: use this sb.append(String.format("<font color=\"%s\">%s</font>","red",text);

Comment: @DHARMENDRASINGH When implementing this, it now shows "<font color=\"%s\">%s</font>","red", in the readout with the other text. It's reading the font color like a string rather than a format change.